# Edit impassable Mountain Range

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I want to do some map editing in the Alpine region but don't know how to move/remove impassable mountain ranges.

I already looked in the `PATH_TO_CK2\map` folder and found in the terrain.txt

```
impassable_mountains = {
    color = { 128 128 128 }
    movement_cost = 2.0
    bottleneck_chance = 35
}
```

but don't know how this is connected to the map and to provinces and their borders.

Do I have to edit the terrain.bmp or do I have to change some textfile?

Comment: Why do you have the mods tag include in your question?

Comment: I think they want to make a mod..

Comment: Because the question is about modifying the map and not a general question about gameplay (like many others here).

Comment: @CodeChimpy I don't think that's a proper use of the "mods" tag. The mods tag is intended for questions about mods for games you're using, not when trying to find some way to modify some aspect of a game-- that, I think, falls under resource recommendation, which we don't do.

Comment: OK, I removed the mods tag and extended the question.

Comment: If we accept questions about modding minecraft there's no reason why we shouldn't accept this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer on this thread: https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/edit-mountain-passes.1028666/#post-22967451

I just have to add/remove black lines between provinces.